# In a mongodb document, how can I set the value of an inner array matched by two variables

Tags: arrays, mongodb

I have the following data structure in my mongodb (v3.2):

```
   {
    'user_id':'abc',
    'samples':[
        {'year':2017,'month':9,'value':10},
        {'year':2017,'month':10,'value':0},
        {'year':2017,'month':11,'value':30}
    ]
   }
```

I am trying to modify the items inside the samples array using the following command:

```
db.COLLECTION.update(
  {'user_id':'abc','samples.year':2017,'samples.month':11},
  {$set:{'samples.$.value':200}})
```

The problem is that this query is updating the first one in the array (month:09) and not the one that I want (month:11). If I remove the year information and use only the month, it works.

Can anyone help me to solve this mystery? At first I was using pymongo, but since it was not working I am using the mongo console directly and still not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that the `find` isn't positioning correctly.

Try using [`$elemmatch`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/#op._S_elemMatch) to locate the item in the array to make the position selection clearer:

```
db.Foos.update({ 
    'user_id':'abc', 
    'samples': {$elemMatch: { 'year' : 2017, 'month':11}}},
   {
       $set:{"samples.$.value":200}
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [$elemMatch](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/) to query object arrays, especially if you are using multiple fields of those inner objects. Your query should be like this:

```
db.COLLECTION.update({
    'user_id':'abc','samples': {$elemMatch: 'year':2017, 'month':11},
{$set:{'samples.$.value':200}
})
```

Comment: Your both solutions are very similar but I had to accept who replied first. I upvoted you anyway. Thanks for your answer.